# expected an intended block calculator

Tags: python

hi im doing a calculator but i gt expected intended block i tried deleting the part when it came out that error but no luck any help would be appreciated.And also can someone teach me how to use while lopp or add a while loop in this code?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import Font
def button(frame, text, command=None):
    ft = Font(family=('Verdana'), size=14)
    return Button(frame, text=text, font=ft, width=3, command=command)
def frame(frame, side=LEFT, bg="black"):
    f = Frame(frame, background=bg, padx=5, pady=5)
    f.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    return f
class App:
    def __init__(self, tk):
        ft = Font(family=('Verdana'), size=14)
        main = frame(tk)
        l_frame = frame(main)
        r_frame = frame(main)
        calc_frame = frame(l_frame)

        self.input = Entry(calc_frame, font=ft, width=15, background="white")
        self.input.pack(side=TOP)
        self.input.bind_all('<BackSpace>', self.cleanInput)
        self.btn_frame = frame(calc_frame)
        x, y = 0, 0
        for key in ("()%C", "+-*/", "1234", "5678", "90.="):
            for c in key:
                if c == "=":
                    btn = button(self.btn_frame, c, self.equalAction)
                elif c == "C":
                    btn = button(self.btn_frame, c, self.cleanAction)
                else:
                    btn = button(self.btn_frame, c, lambda i=c: self.input.insert(INSERT, i))
                btn.grid(row=x, column=y)
                y += 1
            x += 1
            y = 0
        self.log = Text(r_frame, font=Font(family=('Verdana'), size=10), width=25, height=14, background="yellow")
        self.log.pack(side=RIGHT)
    def cleanAction(self):
    self.input.delete(0, END)
def cleanInput(self, event):
    self.input.delete(0, END)
    self.log.delete(1.0, END)
    else:
    btn = button(self.btn_frame, c, lambda i=c: self.input.insert(INSERT, i))
    main.bind_all(c, lambda event, i=c:self.input.insert(INSERT, i))
    def equalAction(self):
        tmp = self.input.get()
        try:
            result = tmp + "=" + str(eval(tmp))
            self.log.insert(1.0, result + "\n");
            print(result)
        except Exception:
            self.log.insert(1.0, "Wrong expression\n");
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Calculator")
    root.geometry()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: In general, instead of saying "i gt expected intended block", copy and paste the actual error and traceback.

Answer (score 2):

The expected block ist in the lines where

```
def cleanAction(self):
self.input.delete(0, END)
```

it should be

```
def cleanAction(self):
    self.input.delete(0, END)
```

Python requires you to indent your code nicely all the time as the indentation is part of the syntax. In the case above, the second line is the command that is executed in the defined function cleanAction(). The interpreter expects a line after the function is defined and tells you about it.

Concerning the loops: the best would be to start off with something like https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Comment: i got invalid syntax error at the else part

Comment: True.. since you have resolved the problem, the interpreter now runs into the next one: As user2357112 pointed out, you are missing an *if*-statement in *cleanInput()* where you are using *else:*.

Comment: so i should replace else with if?

Comment: You should know that better than I.. I have no idea, what you want to do in those lines. Also the indentation of equalAction() is messed up and will probably cause the next error, once you fix the if-issue. Surely, replacing else with if will not fix the issue, cf. for example http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/ifstatements.html on how to use them.

Comment: i wanted to be able to b ackspace the last number entered, clear the last equation

Comment: can someone tell me what i must do now?

Comment: Well.. why is there an *else* in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

```
    def cleanAction(self):
    self.input.delete(0, END)
```

Your indentation starts screwing up here. `cleanInput` is also messed up. It's indented wrong, and there's an `else` without an `if`.